# React component isn't subscribing to the redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I created component and connected it using connect() like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { users: state.users.users }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return { userActions: bindActionCreators(UserActions, dispatch) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Test)
```

Sadly when I open React tools in chrome I get this:[image]
Changing the state isn't forcing component to update. Why it isn't subscribing to it?

**EDIT:**

I'm changing state through action creator and reducer. This is how it looks like:

```
export function addUser(user) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:4200/users/add/user', {user:user})
      .then(() => dispatch({
        type: USER_ADD,
        user: user
      })).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}

export function getUsers() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4200/users')
    .then((response) => dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_USERS,
      users:response.data
    })).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

and reducer:

```
export function users(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_ADD':
      {
        return {
      ...state,
      users: [
        ...state.users,
        action.user
      ]
    }
        break;
      }
    case 'REQUEST_USERS':
      {
        return {
          ...state,
          users: [
            action.users
          ]
        }
        break;
      }
      .........
```

and this is my full component:

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      login: "",
      password: ""
    }
  }

  handleLoginInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({login: e.target.value})
  }

  handlePasswordInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({password: e.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let user = {login:this.state.login, 
password:this.state.password,userId:Math.floor(Math.random()*(100000))};
    this.props.userActions.addUser(user);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="test">
        <form>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleLoginInputChange} value=
{this.state.login} placeholder="login"/>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handlePasswordInputChange} 
value={this.state.password} placeholder="pass"/>
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>send</button>
        </form>
        <UsersList users = {this.props.users} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.userActions.getUsers();
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { users: state.users.users }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { userActions: bindActionCreators(UserActions, dispatch) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Test)
```

I've added everything to github so you could see it [github](https://github.com/Kreha6/reactNotes/tree/master/client/src).

Things that could interest you are in reducers/users.js, actions/useractions and in components/Test.js.

My state after getting data from server looks like this:[image].

I tried many different approaches. Right now I gave up changing the state after adding new user. Instead of that I've made button which can get data from the server - it's reloading the page so I'm not pleased with that solution

Comment: How r u changing the redux state? through action dispatch and reducer? Please post more code.

Comment: Your component is connected, show other code,

Comment: what happens when you click on `send`. After the AJAX request is done, is there an action being dispatched? How is the store being modified as a result from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that this is correct?

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { users: state.users.users }
}
```

how are you binding your reducer to the store? The state might be different from what you expect in `connect`. Can you post what the store contains after the component gets mounted?